Effective 'generator' of semigroup restricted to non-invariant subspace
Let $H: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be a densely defined, self-adjoint, non-negative operator.
Let $P: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow  \mathcal{H} $ be an orthogonal projection onto a subspace.
We may define an effective version of $H$ acting on the subspace $P\mathcal{H}$ as
$$
\tilde{H} = -\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac1t P[e^{-tH}- Id]P = -[\partial_tPe^{-tH}P]_{t = 0}
$$
with domain $\tilde{\mathcal{D}}$ consisting of those elements $\psi$ of $P\mathcal{H}$ for which the limit $-\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac1t P[e^{-tH}- Id]P \psi$ exists.
I am especially interested in the case of finite dimensional $P$, where no domain issues exist.
What is known about the operator $\tilde{H}$?
Are there references studying such a setting available?
